# Function that returns a type behaves differently if it is a property of an object

Tags: typescript

I've notice some odd behaviour:

In an ordinary case, TypeScript will complain if an object contains *too many* keys, like so:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: string; 
}

const a: Foo = {
  a: "hello", 
  b: "foo" //  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
}; 

function returnsFoo() : Foo {
  return {
    a: 'hello', 
    b: "world" //   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
  }
}
```

However, if instead of directly declaring a function, I'm declaring a type that has a function as property, this error goes away:

```
type ObjectThatHasAFunctionThatReturnsFoo = {
  defaultData: () => Foo; 
}; 

const b: ObjectThatHasAFunctionThatReturnsFoo = {
  defaultData: ()=> ({
    a: "hello", 
    //@ts-expect-error - but no error. 
    b: "asa"
  })
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:
>
> One final way to get around these checks, which might be a bit surprising, is to assign the object to another variable: Since squareOptions won’t undergo excess property checks, the compiler won’t give you an error.

I believe that you don't have an error here:

```js
type Foo = {
    a: string;
}

const a: Foo = {
    a: "hello",
    b: "foo" //  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
};

function returnsFoo(): Foo {
    return {
        a: 'hello',
        b: "world" //   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
    }
}

type ObjectThatHasAFunctionThatReturnsFoo = {
    defaultData: () => Foo;
};


const b: ObjectThatHasAFunctionThatReturnsFoo = {
    defaultData: () => ({
        a: "hello",
        b: "foo"
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqBDALigGdgAnASwDsBzAbiwF8ssBjOK0-I%20RFDbLkJQARAAsIAG0lwRAGiy4oAIyIiAZghFQA9DpwB5ZQCsIrYFEkVgEMnklQAtnhBQOk18UisK61wGsqOAB3KigwMjhIMmAKCGI5fCoAEygAcmU0qGS4eKggiwgADwouaihQSHTeNIA6AAoAJgBmRsaASiYGTCx1AFcqcwoOKDIIYD6yTl569p4ENEVcMYmpxcElHGE0iWk4NIUNzdVRYLgySWTtPVwjU3NLa1t7Jxc3Kg8Sb18AoNDwyLRWLxRJ4FLpTLZXLEfJwQolMphSrQNI1BotNqdI7MTA4rDIqB3MzAAAqYjwwAAEnhiABBGADIYcMkUgBK40m0wW-CWOGSEHUeD6kmAABEKcJZsgAHywBDdRjdFiYdicCwnInmFlUmn0xmxZnk4Ds1ZcvjrJT8wXCsUSohSpCy%20oCTZCNS7GTyXnHNSaWTexhYnFAA)

because function `foo` is de-facto assigned to `defaultData` prop.

Because you neither assign object literal to other variable nor using it as argument - there is no excess property checks

> That's correct - that extra b property means that a developer has made a mistake

In order to do it, you might want to make some validation:

```js
type Foo = {
    a: string;
}

type Valid = {
    defaultData: () => Foo;
};
type Validation<T> =
    T extends { defaultData: infer Fn }
    ? Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any
    ? ReturnType<Fn> extends Foo
    ? Foo extends ReturnType<Fn>
    ? T
    : never
    : never
    : never
    : never

const builder = <T extends Valid>(arg: Validation<T>) => arg

builder({
    defaultData: () => ({  // expected error
        a: "hello",
        b: "foo"
    })
})

builder({
    defaultData: () => ({  // ok
        a: "hello",
    })
})
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/type-negation#generic_constraints), in my blog, you can find more information about generic validation

Comment: To be clear - I _want_ the excess property checking.

Comment: So, you have data structure which is represented by `ObjectThatHasAFunctionThatReturnsFoo` interface and you want TS to complain about extra `b` property, correct?

Comment: That's correct - that extra `b` property means that a developer has made a mistake.