# What is an 'object literal' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I see the term 'object literal' used a lot in TypeScript (eg [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68358441/1068446)) - what do we actually mean by 'object literal' and how is it different just an 'object'?

Here's some relevant documentation in the official documentation:

[Object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html)

> In JavaScript, the fundamental way that we group and pass around data is through objects. In TypeScript, we represent those through object types.

[Literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)

> In addition to the general types string and number, we can refer to specific strings and numbers in type positions.

So I understand the concept of literal types, when we are referring to strings or numbers, where you're talking about narrower, specific value. eg `"bob"` rather than the wider `string`.

What exactly is an object literal?

Comment: Same as in JavaScript… also known as an object initializer, an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is an object written as a set of properties inside curly braces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object literal is when you use curly brackets to create an object, as in:

```
const example = { hello: "world" };
```

That's in comparison to creating an instance of a class, as in:

```
const now = new Date();
```

(Note: object literals exist in plain javascript too, not just typescript)

Comment: Fantastic thank you - pointing out that it's a javascript thing is the key thing here.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript handbook indeed doesn't explain this, but it's very simple. It's basically whenever you use the JS object notation syntax (`{ ... }`) to create an object. TypeScript sees that as an object literal, which gets some extra type checking.

When you use an object literal for a type, it'll actually check whether your literal contains keys that don't exist in the target type. Usually this type checking is glanced over (e.g. you can assign an `Apple` to a `Fruit` variable). Object literals get actually checked during creation. *There are also some other special interactions when using object literals for generic parameters.*